# Bootstrap4 NavBar, Transparent on scroll down, bg-colour on scroll up but back to transparent before the top

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Using WordPress and Bootstrap 4's navbar I want to add the effect where the navbar at the top of the page is transparent, fadesOut when scrolled down, fadeIn (with background colour) on scroll up but before it reaches the top fadesOut the background colour to transparent.

I've used the jQuery from [this example](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/bootstrap/bootstrap4-navbar-hide-when-scroll-down/) but I don't know how to add the 'before I reach the top remove background colour'.

Example code:

```
    $(function () {
      var lastScrollTop = 0;
      var $navbar = $('.navbar');

      $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (st > lastScrollTop) { // scroll down

          // use this is jQuery full is used
          $navbar.fadeOut()

          // use this to use CSS3 animation
          // $navbar.addClass("fade-out");
          // $navbar.removeClass("fade-in");

          // use this if no effect is required
          // $navbar.hide();
        } else { // scroll up

          // use this is jQuery full is used
          $navbar.fadeIn()

          // use this to use CSS3 animation
          // $navbar.addClass("fade-in");
          // $navbar.removeClass("fade-out");

          // use this if no effect is required
          // $navbar.show();
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
      });
    });
```

The closest [example I've found](https://codepen.io/bewley/pen/GZBQRr) used the navbar and div to workout out scroll height to make the change, but I don't want to rely on a div id.

```
    //jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
    var header_height  = $('.navbar').height(),
        intro_height    = $('.intro-section').height(),
        offset_val = intro_height + header_height;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top >= offset_val) {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("navbar-transparent");
        } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
          $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("navbar-transparent");
        }
    });
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example You've found is using Bootstrap 3, please note that there are major differences between Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4.

In bootstrap 4 you can add classes like `.sticky-top` to make your Navbar sticky and `.bg-transparent` to make it transparent.

Here is a working example:

```js
(function ($) {

    var navbar = $('.navbar');
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        // Scroll down
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            navbar.fadeOut();
        } 
        // Scroll up but still lower than 200 (change that to whatever suits your need)
        else if(st < lastScrollTop && st > 200) {
            navbar.fadeIn();
            navbar.removeClass('navbar-light bg-transparent').addClass('navbar-dark bg-custom');
        }
        // Reached top
        else {
            navbar.removeClass('navbar-dark bg-custom').addClass('navbar-light bg-transparent');
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* For testing purposes */
body {
    height: 2000px;
}

/* Set your background color */
.bg-custom {
    background-color: #333
}
/* Transition effect */
.navbar {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-transparent">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also note that you should use the default WordPress jQuery rather than the `slim` version linked in Bootstrap 4 page which doesn't includes many functions like `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`

Comment: that's perfect!! Thank you.

Comment: I should have clarified before, the code example where just examples of the effect I was trying for. Using the code examples I did migrate everything Bootstrap4 and use WP's full jQuery rather. I just couldn't get the if else if statement right. Thanks for the code comments as well, really helpful!